# Get the height of optional text

Tags: text, height, box

I would like to create a cover page with latex, with optional fields, such that other fields get their position depending on whether the optional field exists or not.

I found the trick of using `\savebox` and `\ht\mybox` but I get inconsistent height when the only thing in the box is a variable. The height is not well adjusted depending on whether the variable is a text or empty, and if it is text, if it has one or more lines.

Here is a minimal working example. Normally, the text "Not optional" should always stick at the top of the page, but it changes position when the text in variable `\texttoprew` changes, while I was expecting the negative `\vspace` to compensate for these changes. Any idea why?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}

\makeatletter
\def\texttoprew#1{\def\@texttoprew{#1}}
\def\textbot#1{\def\@textbot{#1}}

\def\maketitle{
    \newsavebox{\titbox}
    \sbox{\titbox}{%
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \@texttoprew
    \end{minipage}
    }
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \newgeometry{left=2cm, right=2cm, top=0in, bottom=0in}
    \parskip 0pt
    \parindent 0pt
    \if \@texttoprew\empty
    \else
        \usebox{\titbox}
        \vspace{-\ht\titbox}
    \fi

    \@textbot
}

\makeatother
% changing this variable (texttoprew) between empty {} and one or several line text
% changes the position of the text in textbot
\texttoprew{regreg\\ewfewf\\ewfewfwfe\\ewewfqwf\\ewfewf}
\textbot{Not Optional}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

I know that to get the text sticking at the top of the page there are other options, my problem arises in much more complicated cases, this is just a MWE.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to the site.  It is not clear what you are looking for, but one suggestion is to add alignment to the `minipage`, default is `[c]`, try `[t]` or `[b]`.  It will change the result, though I don't know the goal here.  Generally, the box will have both `\ht` and `\dp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guessed at what the OP meant and apparently was successful.

I used `[t]`op alignment of the `minipage` so that the `\texttoprew` text would always grow downward.  Because it is in a box, I added a `\strut` at the beginning, so that it's top line positioning would not depend on the height of the content in the first line (`xxx` vs. `XXX` for example).

However, the top alignment of the `minipage` means most of the boxes vertical dimension is depth rather than height.  So I made sure the vertical shift was a combination of them, as in `-\dimexpr\ht\titbox+\dp\titbox`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}

\makeatletter
\def\texttoprew#1{\def\@texttoprew{#1}}
\def\textbot#1{\def\@textbot{#1}}

\def\maketitle{
    \newsavebox{\titbox}
    \sbox{\titbox}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
    \strut\@texttoprew
    \end{minipage}
    }
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \newgeometry{left=2cm, right=2cm, top=0in, bottom=0in}
    \parskip 0pt
    \parindent 0pt
    \if \@texttoprew\empty
    \else
        \usebox{\titbox}
        \vspace{-\dimexpr\ht\titbox+\dp\titbox}
    \fi

    \@textbot
}

\makeatother
% changing this variable (texttoprew) between empty {} and one or several line text
% changes the position of the text in textbot
\texttoprew{regreg\\ewfewf\\ewfewfwfe\\ewewfqwf\\ewfewf}
\textbot{Not Optional}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Not sure why the slight discrepancy of overlaid lines.  One could manually compensate with a `\vspace` of `-\dimexpr.95\ht\titbox+\dp\titbox`, instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot! If you have any comments on why you need `\strut` and what is the depth of a box, that would be great! Thanks in any case!